# htaccess clean profile links

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

At the moment I'm using the following HTACCESS code

```
RewriteEngine On

# Lose the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Clean profile URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

So the links do work when I go to http://mysite.com/username, I see the profile. But I can also still use the http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=username.

What I want is that that second on is being directed to the short version of http://mysite.com/username.

Another problem is that when I surf to http://www.mysite.com/username, it wil rewrite the url as http://mysite.com/profile.php?user=username.

Also, how can I avoid this for certain folders like my images folder? If i go to the images folder I get http://mysite.com/images/?user=images

Also if there is a slash behind the clean url, the page acts weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Last action on the change url rule. I changed my code to the following:

```
# Lose the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Exclude existing files from redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]

# Clean profile URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ http://businessgame.be/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

This seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is not yet live I would not worry about the /profile.php?user=username urls. Since people will have to know that there is a php file names profile.php. If you never create any links in your html to profile.php directly, no one will know.

If the site is live already, let us know.

As for the images problem.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^images/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

to also do a css and/or js folder

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|css|js)/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

The last problem of the tailing slash most likely has to do with the use of relative urls in your html. Try replacing `href="path/resource.ext"` with `href="/path/resource.ext"`. Same for `src="..."` etc.

Comment: Next time remove your question. I don't like wasting my time :-)